# python - How to change a line chart into a bar chart?

Tags: python, charts, histogram

is anybody who know how to change [line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKIC5.png) to [bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pabFo.png)?

there is a code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (18,12))
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
img = skimage.data.chelsea()
color = ('r','g','b')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
labels= ["red","green", "blue"]
plt.legend(labels)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
plt.plot(histr, color = col)
```

to

```
x = np.arrange(len(histr))
plt.bar(x, histr, color = col)
```

[matplotlib bar chart documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)